# For Loops, i and Strings Troubles in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, string, for-loop, append

I'm trying to append a string with a number and I'm using a for loop to do it. For some reason though I'm getting the error "Expected identifier."

How do I get rid of this issue in objective C?

```
  for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)
{
    int num = 0;
    num = num + i;
NSString *current = [@"/current%d.html", num];

NSString *filePath = [basePath stringByAppendingString:current];
 //   NSLog(@"current");
```

Here's a snippet of my code where I'm getting the error.

Comment: Declaring num within the for loop does nothing. num is equal to i. 0 plus i is just i.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `[@"/current%d.html", num];` to

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/current%d.html", num];`

When you enclose your statement in `[]`, Obj-C expects the statement to be a message-receiver pair. Here the `+(NSString *)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)` class method receives the `NSSting` `@"/current%d.html", num"` message/parameter.

Don't know all the proper terminology, but thats the get of it I believe.

And as Josue pointed out, `num` will be the same as `i` in your code. Perhaps you meant to initialize before the `for` loop?